# font rendering issue in safari

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

Hi currently i am working on one WordPress themes in which front page of theme look good on all browser but in safari when we go to any other page header of page which have heading ,tagline and on right side having small menu and contact detail goes wired means it's font goes more lighter than front page i need all consistent on all pages.

theme URL is here

please see in safari

Frontpage - http://demo.wpgothemes.com/minn

you can see any other page e.g -http://demo.wpgothemes.com/minn/page-layouts/3-col-content-center/

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It solved by just adding

```
body
{
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works well.